# moving textview pixel by pixel every one second in Android

Tags: android, textview, runnable

I have a TextView in my Android App. I want to move that TextView every second pixel by pixel. I am using setX method for moving the textView. It works fine if i use a button and click it. With every click the textview moves but when i try to automate it using a loop with handler it is not moving smooth, it just rushes to the left of the screen without delay. This is the code i am using

```
    int i = (int) txtView.getX();    
    while (i>0)
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
             @Override
            public void run()
            {
               txtView.setX((int) txtView.getX() - 1);
            }
        }, 1000)
    i--;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are setting the posDelayed actions without any dealy. you are setting the delay before execution of runnable. But there is no delay between two iteration of your while loop

perhapse you can do something like this

```
      handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

      Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
             @Override
            public void run()
            {
               txtView.setX((int) txtView.getX() - 1);

               i--;
               if(i>0)
                    handler.postDelayed(r,1000);
            }
        }
```

Comment: why does he need a loop. he can use a handler or timer which runs with a delay of 1 second right?

Comment: @Raghunandan i haven't used any loop.. and the answer is only a proposal :). Please correct me with your kind suggestion

Comment: oh. ok. i misunderstood because of the variable i used

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = (int) txtView.getX();    
while (i>0)
{
    txtView.setX((int) txtView.getX() - 1);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    i--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this class

```
 public class TypeWriter extends TextView {

    private CharSequence mText;
    private int mIndex;
    private long mDelay = 500; //Default 500ms delay

    public TypeWriter(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TypeWriter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable characterAdder = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            batterLevel.setText(mText.subSequence(0, mIndex++));
            if(mIndex <= mText.length()) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);
            }
        }
    };

    public void animateText(CharSequence text) {
        mText = text;
        mIndex = 0;

        batterLevel.setText("");
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(characterAdder);
        mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);
    }


    public void setCharacterDelay(long millis) {
        mDelay = millis;
    }
}
```

and to use it from your activity call as below

```
 private TypeWriter writer;


 writer = new TypeWriter(getActivity());
 writer.setCharacterDelay(150);
 writer.animateText(todisplay);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with AsyncTask:

```
private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {    

    private Button mMyButton;

    public Task(Button myButton) {
        mMyButton = myButton;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v)
    {
        mMyButton.setX(mMyButton.getX() + 1);
    }
}
```

and when you want it to move your element, do this:

```
int pixels = 50;
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
for( int i = 0; i < pixels; ++i) {
    new Task(myButton).execute();
}
```

Of course you change Button to what ever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have a delay in the actual loop. So after one second, all the Runnables you posted to your Handler will get executed sequentially without delay.

Add the delay in between the actual calls in your code. Rough code below :

```
//Handler used to post to UI thread.
final Handler handler = new Handler();

new Thread()
{
    int i = (int) txtView.getX();    
        while (i>0)
        {
            handler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                 @Override
                public void run()
                {
                   txtView.setX((int) txtView.getX() - 1);
                }
            });
        i--;

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //Add exception catching code
      }
}.start();
```

Also,a 1000 ms delay isn't very smooth. Try something a little faster.